# How to turn my project from multiple compilation unit into a single compilation unit in Eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, build, build-process

I have a "standard " project in eclipse with source and header files included. Although all the source files within the project are compiled, despite of the fact that these source files are not included by the `main.c` where is the main routine.

What I want is only one compilation unit (one source file to be compiled) and the other source files to be included `#include "some-folder/some-file.c"`directly. Not to be compiled separately as it is now.

I tried to remove the path to those files from the **Build variables** but they are still compiled individually.

Please guide me how to achieve what I want.

Comment: Just for my personal curiosity, why do you need that ?

Comment: Why oh why would you do that? It won't save much build-time, in fact it will be almost the opposite as a little change in a single source file will cause the whole project to be rebuilt instead of just the single source file.

Comment: I am curious as well ! I don't even know what are benefits of this approach. I suppose it has something to do with the resource usage optimization, since we are developing embedded application software. So the direct answer is: It is the boss fad.

Comment: What do you mean by "resource usage optimization"? You won't save any space in the data, code or bss segments. It won't help at all with any possible heap usage, or any other dynamic resource usage. The only thing I see is that the compiler might be more aggressive with inlining, which will make the code larger but slightly faster.

Comment: I guess this:
If some global function in some source file isn't called by the main routine, there wont be separated space into the flash for that function. Because the compiler knows that this function is not called. But the linker has no way to know that. It is my opinion.

Comment: @joach if your compiler is missing link time optimization, it could have some benefits.

Comment: @Hairi That is not how linkers work... otherwise for example every program written for Windows would link the whole Windows API to it and become an enormous executable. Only functions that are actually used are linked to your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the C tools and, like others, don't know why you would do this but can you put the other source files in a separate folder that isn't marked as a source folder? The source files in the "non source" folder shouldn't be compiled automatically.